# ANTLR4 UnsupportedOperationException (Serialized ATN data element 85257 element 11 out of range 0..65535) while generating code for large grammars

Tags: c#, antlr4

When generating code for large grammars I'm getting this exception log. The code generation targets C#.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Serialized ATN data element 85257 element 11 out of range 0..65535
 at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATNSerializer.serialize(ATNSerializer.java:362)
 at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATNSerializer.getSerialized(ATNSerializer.java:601)
 at org.antlr.v4.Tool.generateInterpreterData(Tool.java:745)
 at org.antlr.v4.Tool.processNonCombinedGrammar(Tool.java:400)
 at org.antlr.v4.Tool.process(Tool.java:361)
 at org.antlr.v4.Tool.processGrammarsOnCommandLine(Tool.java:328)
 at org.antlr.v4.Tool.main(Tool.java:172)
```

How can fix this exception? I'm trying to simplify the grammar.

Comment: Could you share the grammar that you are using?

Comment: For privacy reasons I'm not allowed to share the grammar here, so I had contact you through your github contact email. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this? I believe it's due to the grammar being too big, but I don't know how to solve this. Any solution would be appreciated.